# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un campo sea auto incrementable desde DbContex?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estoy creando tablas desde DbContext y necesitó crear la tabla **Usuarios** que contiene los siguientes campos:

```
Id INT Auto Incrementable, 
UserName Varchar (50) Clave Primaria, 
Password Varchar (50)
```

Pero no sé cómo hacer para que el campo Id se incremente de uno en uno cada vez que inserto un nuevo usuario.

Escribi esto :

```
   public class Usuarios
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Cuando ejecuto un Insert Me dice que el campo Id no acepta valores nulos

Codigo para Insertar

```
public static  int InsertarUsuario(RegisterData Usuario)
        {
            int resultado = new int();
            SqlConnection Conexion = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
            using (Conexion)
            {
                Conexion.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Sp_InsertarUsuario", Conexion);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Usuario.UserName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Usuario.Password);
                resultado = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Conexion.Close();
            }
            return resultado;
        }
```

Stored Procedure

```
USE [MvcPractice]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_InsertarUsuario] 
       (
            @UserName VARCHAR(50),
            @Password VARCHAR(50)
       )
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
   INSERT INTO Usuarios (UserName, Password) VALUES (@UserName, @Password);
END ;
```

Comment: Tu código es correcto, ya se incrementa automáticamente, cuando crees un objeto, no asignes el `Id`, al momento de ejecutar `SaveChanges()` automáticamente va a agregar el siguiente `Id`

Comment: Cuando intento agregar un registro me dice  que el campo Id no acepta valores nulos

Comment: No lo había notado, porque usas un campo autoincremental si otro campo es tu clave primaria? Si podes, edita la pregunta y agrega el cómo haces el insert de tus entidades

Comment: Uso el campo UserName como clave principal por que no quiero que se repita, el campo Id debe ser un entero que se incremente con cada registro de uno en uno

Comment: Posiblemente tu problema esta en el hecho de que uses un Stored Procedure, poque Entity Framework al campo `Id`, asumo casi con seguridad que lo creo para que no permita null, es así?

Answer (score 1):

La key de la tabla no puede ser el `UserName` eso es incorrecto, primero debes definir el campo `Id` como `key` y `identity`

Ahora bien si quieres que el `UserName` no se duplique lo debes definir como `UNIQUE` asi se valida el constraint y se evitan duplicados al insertar

Lo puedes hacer desde el diseñador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero remarco el campo key es el que se autoincrementa

Comment: Ok...Pero lo ideal seria definir el UNIQUE desde la clase Usuarios en el codigo C#..Como puedo hacerlo ?

Comment: si usas EF Core se puede definir https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes aunque no se si se pueda indicar que sea UNIQUE, sino al aplicar migrations se podria poner manualmente la creacion del indice